# What purpose does a queue serve in System Verilog?

Tags: system-verilog, verification

1. They are not used for RTL but rather verification, correct? They would not be synthesizable.
2. Do they have better memory management features in turn optimizing program time? If I recall
   correctly, System Verilog has an automatic garbage collector, so there is no need to deallocate memory.
3. The official IEEE documentation does a great job of explaining how they work. I am just wondering in what scenarios I would use one vs an array. One guess would be that they have associated methods that allow for easier data manipulation?

Thank you in advance for your knowledge and expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A queue can be synthesisable if it has a bounded maximum size. Only a few synthesis tools support it, probably none of the FPGA synthesis tools.
2. The key advantage with a queue is in efficiency adding/removing one element from the array, especially when accessed at the head or tail of the queue. A dynamic array may require reallocation and copying the entire array when modifying its size. The penalty for a queue is the extra time it takes to access elements in the middle of the queue, and extra space compared with the same number of element of a dynamic array.
3. I hope that 2 answers this question.